# Adding a default value to a column while creating table in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I want  to add a default value to a column while creating a migration.

How can I do this? Help me please.

Comment: Have you tried going to google and search "laravel default value", click the first link and Ctrl+F search "default" ? I don't want to be rude, but you will get answers much faster, and also it will teach you to be more independent.

Answer (score 4):

```
->default($value)
```

is what you need.

Specify a "default" value for the column.
Like

```
$table->boolean('is_verified')->default(0);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Add `->default($value)` to your clause, for example:

```
$table->text('description')->default('There is no description yet');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#writing-migrations

Answer (score 0):

follow this [Faker link](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker). here You can create and initialize a faker generator, which can generate data by accessing properties named after the type of data you want.